# Proof verification: For all $g\in G$, with $G$ being a group, $|a|=|g^{-1}ag|$.

Tags: proof-verification, cyclic-groups

Can someone please verify whether my proof is logically correct? :)

> For all $g\in G$, with $G$ being a group, $|a|=|g^{-1}ag|$.

**Proof:** Let $|a|=n$. Then $a^{n}=e$. Then $e=g^{-1}g=g^{-1}eg=g^{-1}a^{n}g=(g^{-1}ag)^{n}$. Then $|g^{-1}ag|=n=|a|$. $\square$

Comment: Recall, the order of an element $g$ is the **smallest** positive integer $k$ such that $g^k=e$. So showing $g^k=e$ is not sufficient to show $k=|g|$, we also need to show that $g^j\neq e$ for any integer $0<j<k$.

Comment: To show that $|g^{-1}ag| = |a|$, you can simplify $g^{-1}a^{k}g$ to $a^{k}$, and you know that one of the inherent characteristics of $a$ is that it has order $n$, so you can say that the smallest $k$ such that $a^{k} = e$ is $n$. What you did is assume $a^{n} = e$ and show that it also satisfies the right hand side. However, there is no guarantee that it is the smallest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you have proven that $|g^{-1}ag|\leq |a|$ (yes, maybe the order is smaller).

You still need to prove the other inequality.